# jQuery Plugin for Social Popout Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

I have been looking for a plugin for a while now and very surprised to not be able to find one.

Everyone has seen those websites where there is a side tab or ribbon that says like "Help" or "Feedback" and you click it. Then a little menu or panel pops out.

I am looking to do something like that on my site which uses bootstrap.

Does anyone know if there is a bootstrap / css solution or a jQuery plugin to do this?

I found this but it is using an older version of jQuery and I couldn't get it to work with my setup.

http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

That's exactly what I need, though.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be quite a few.

How does this one look? It's called jQuery Sidebar and is by sideroad:

website: http://sideroad.secret.jp/plugins/jQuerySideBar/

github: https://github.com/sideroad/jquery.sidebar

---

And here is a list of more if that doesn't work.

http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-sliding-sidebar-panel-plugins/